# Passing arguments from Eclipse to TestNG

Tags: java, eclipse, unit-testing, testing, testng

I am looking for a way to do a test method in TestNG such that when I click in a certain file in Eclipse and make Run -> TestNG, it will pass that selected file's full name and the test receives that same file name as argument.

Is this possible to do with TestNG? I know how to make Eclipse send the correct argument, I am not just sure how to make TestNG accept it.

Thanks

Comment: You could pass a JVM argument in the launch configuration (-Dfoo=bar) and in your test, use System.getProperty(...) to retrieve it.

Comment: Yes, that's what I ended up doing (I passed an environmental variable...) but that is just a hack. I am looking for something better, if possible..

Comment: You can also define parameters in a testng.xml file and declare that file to be an "XML template" (look this up in the Eclipse doc).

Comment: Can you clarify what you're trying to do? If you just want to be able to run a single unit test file in eclipse the TestNG plugin should take care of that.

Answer (score -1):

This is kind of hacky... but you could try instantiating it from Ant. Rather than write a build.xml just [call the testNG task](http://testng.org/javadoc/org/testng/TestNGAntTask.html) directly and feed it the class/file name. That way all the work is done for you. Also I believe that TestNG requires it's own JVM when it's running, so this will take care of that as well.

Edit: I think I misread your question.